# Download images to server

Tags: php, image, joomla

I have a JavaScript application on a page in Joomla which generates a graphic (png). I want to save this image to the image directory. Doing this with JavaScript is not possible for safety reasons. Is there in Joomla a PHP call which can be used to get this done?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Joomla media manager `file.json.php` (for ajax use) or `file.php` controllers (from `administrator/components/com_media/controllers`)

Either will do, but you need to fulfill the requirements i.e.

- having a valid login
- passing along a security token
- giving the user or user group privileges to upload (in media manager - options - permissions tab).

This should be enough to get you started.